# Cannot register/resolve AutoMapper.IMapper in .net Maui ---- System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid generic arguments'

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper, maui

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{

    public static IMapper CreateMapper()
    {
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<ModelProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<DtoProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<ItmProfile>();
        });
        return mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    }
}

//Registering my service:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(AutoMapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
```

[image]

I also tried registering with the help of Autofac. I am not getting issues while registering but while resolving the IMapper I am getting the exception "Exception Has Been Thrown by the target of an invocation".

```
container.Register(cfc => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
                    {
                        cfg.AddProfile<ModelProfile>();
                        cfg.AddProfile<DtoProfile>();
                        cfg.AddProfile<ItmProfile>();
                    }));

                   container.Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper()).As<IMapper>()
                       .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Comment: Please at the full exception details including stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions to your post.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Adding "AutoMapper" 13.0, I get access to the "AddAutoMapper" method. Then as mentioned in the document I added my profiles to it. It worked for me. You saved my day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the post shared by @LucianBargaoanu, by Adding "AutoMapper" 13.0 from Nuget, I get access to the "AddAutoMapper" method. I added my profile to it. It worked for me.

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ModelProfile), typeof(DtoProfile), typeof(ItmProfile));
```

Comment: Exactly, you can mark it as an answer.